# Understanding a Wolfram|Alpha explanation on a simple integral

Tags: calculus, wolfram-alpha

[image: Wolfram Alpha:]

I'll probably kick myself when someone explains it, but I can't understand where the 1/12 comes from after the re-substitution of u? I thought it would be 1/3, but it clearly isn't. Why is that?

Thanks for input on this.

Comment: Just a word of warning: using Wolfram Alpha should be limited to checking answers (if it is used at all).  I personally believe WA is a crutch that actually undermines ones ability to understand calculus fully.  You have asked a few questions concerning standard trig-substitution.  I would suggest that with this type of problem you put away the computer (math.se and WA alike), sit down with a sheet of paper and try as many examples from a textbook as you can.

Comment: Ok. I thought since it explained the steps it was better than not having someone to consult with questions, but I'll follow your advice then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since x is cubed, when the 1/2 is factored it turns into 1/8. Then 2/3 times 1/8 is 1/12.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now. Thanks